How to align 2 different texts based on whether it's displayed in the same line or not
How to align text B to right when text a and b are in same line and make text B align to left when it goes to next line because of space constraint


.text-left {
  float: left;
  /* Float to the left */
}

.text-right {
  float: right;
  /* Float to the right */
}
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="text-wrapper">
  <span class="text-left">abcfdsdfgdfgfdgfrd</span>
  <span class="text-right">xyzdsffdgdfgdfgds</span>
</div>





Have you tried using Media Queries?

yeah i cant use media queries as the text is dynamic and screen size is not fixed , i mean we cant tell at what browser size the text will have to goto next line.

CSS Flexbox can help with this.
Make the container a flex container, justify the contents with space-between, and set the wrap to wrap.  In this case nothing is technically right-justified, the container is simply maximizing the space between the elements if there is space to do so.
When there isn't enough space for both elements, they wrap to a new line.  And since neither of them are right-justified in any way, when they wrap they are defaulting to the left.


.text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="text-wrapper">
  <span>abcfdsdfgdfgfdgfrd</span>
  <span>xyzdsffdgdfgdfgds</span>
</div>



